# UIWebView + custom javascript object

Tags: javascript, function, object, uiwebview

I'm using a UIWebView with local jquery and a script that defines a function, like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    var myVar;

    function info() {
        alert('info');
    }
}
```

What I cannot accomplish is such a simple task:

```
var myfunc = new myFunc();
myfunc.info();
```

in the UIWebView. How can I instantiate a new object and call a function of that object by using:

```
[webViewObject stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myfunc.info();"];
```

I'm struggling about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved. Is sufficient to implement the  protocol in the viewcontroller you are using it, then declare:

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

and in:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var obj = new myObject();"];
}
```

later:

```
-(void)myAwesomeAction
{
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"obj.func();"];
}
```